# Angular template communication one tick delayed

Tags: angular, ng-template

I've been playing with ng-template and found myself struggling with some kind of delay.

I created one simple example in stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-series-v?file=app%2Fparent%2Fparent1.component.ts

A **Parent** components sends a **Hello** component to its **Child** through templating.

The idea was to control the template from the 
**Child** using an *ngIf*.

When the **Hello** component reachs the *ngOnInit* hook cycle it emits an output. The parent component grabs this output and add a message to display.

But the message isn't displayed when the component is created rather that one cycle later. In the example you need to click twice the button "Toggle content" in order to make the message "Template created" to appear.

How can I address this in order to make the message appear in the same cycle?

Comment: You can have the same behaviour without explictly using ng-template: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-series-v-nugyd4?file=app%2Fparent%2Fparent1.component.ts Just Child -> grandparent communication is delayed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to how change detection works in Angular. It is not linked to using `ng-template`, as this [modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-series-v-nugyd4?file=app%2Fparent%2Fparent1.component.ts) show (using grand child without using ng-template).

2 things to know about change detection:

- it is triggered after events (click, submit,..), xhr requests or timers.
- it occurs from top to bottom of the component tree

Basically, when you click the toggle button:

- the handler is triggered (toggling `showContent`'s value in your example, but nothing else. The `hello` component is **NOT** created at this stage)
- change detection kicks in, always starting from top to bottom.
- angular starts with checking if the view needs to be updated for the parent component. As nothing has changed yet, the parent view is not updated.
- The child component then detects that its `showContentValue` has changed. This causes the creation of the `hello` component.
- After initialisation of the `hello` component, the `created` event is emitted. The parent component received this event and updates the array of messages accordingly. But the parent's content has aleready been checked at this point, so Angular will make no modification to the parent view.

When you click the toggle button again, then the same cycle runs again and this time the message pushed in the array in the previous cycle is displayed

Here is a [modified stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-series-v-xhrmuu?file=app%2Fchild%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts) with logs for lifecycle hooks

**Note**

Forcing change detection to run again will solve your problem here, but if you are not communicating directly from child to parent, you'd better use a shared service (based on observables) to broadcast messages between unrelated components

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're breaking the Angular change detection cycle.

Here is what is happening after you click on your first toggle button :

1- You click on the toggle

2- ZoneJS, which has hooks in click events gets notified (Simply put)

3- Zone makes sure the click event is finished

4- Zone will let Angular know that an `async` event has happened, we must check the component and make sure that the view ( DOM ) is reflecting the model ( the model/the javascript world). So `change detection` will run, and it will detect all the changes and finds that there are bindings in the template (`ng-if`).

5- After `ngIf` becomes true, **AND NOTE THAT THIS IS ALL SYNC SO FAR**, the `ng-container` gets created and your `templateOutlet` gets created and your `hello` component will be rendered.

**NOTE AGAIN : this is all sync.**

6 - View has been updated, change detection is now off the hook.

7 - Inside your `hello` component you fire another event which is the `created` and that notifies the Parent component and inside your parent component you are **mutating the array**, and Angular doesn't care about that because there hasn't been a async event, nor have you updated any of the inputs, you've just fired another sync event after change detection was finished his job.

8- the Array is now updated, but the view is not ( in the parent component)

9 - You click again, the same happens and Angular updates the parent view in the first change detection run and you see the array is being reflected in the view.

To prove that I'm right :D :

```
 onTemplateCreated() {
    console.log('Got the event from chil');
   this.template.push('Template created');
    console.log('this.template',this.template);
  }
```

You'll see that after click , the console is showing the right array, but the view is not untill you click again.

Now let's swich to my code

```
 onTemplateCreated() {
    console.log('Got the event from chil');
   this.template = [...this.template,'Template created'];
  }
```

BEcause I'm not mutating and the refrence is being updated, Angular now has to care about this change, **BUT** there's still an issue, Angular's change detector was finished and you updated the model withouth running any `async` event, so we're in trouble, because Angular doesn't like the model to be updated after the change detection is finished,

So you'll be thrown an error that says :

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value

To fix that, [first read my other post to understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923376/change-detection-cycle-in-angular-clarification/47924029#47924029), second, you need tell Angular that you know what you're doing and run the change detection manually :

```
  this._cd.detectChanges
```

OR , you can make it async :

```
onTemplateCreated() {
    console.log('Got the event from chil');
   setTimeout(()=>{
      this.template = [...this.template,'Template created'];
   })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run changeDetector in parent- it will update page from the first click.

Here is an example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template-series-v-b6ebji?file=app/parent/parent1.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you for anwsering. If  I run changeDetector I'm not just looking for a new cycle? I would like to know why there is a cycle mismatch between the output and the view.

Comment: I think when you just insert component with ng-content - it take one tick. But if you insert template, then ngOutlet creates view with child component - it can take more ticks, and possibly parent properties updates in that case are done after changeDetection cycle. So need to trigger it additionally

Comment: You can try to put template separately and feed it to child as input param. Maybe it will help, but not sure